# Sort polynomial by monomial degree

Tags: polynomials, sorting

there is an equation  :

z =  a^2 + a b + a a' + a a' a'' + a b'

and i want to rearrange the equation by sorting the terms by number of variable multiplication within.

If my English is not well, let me say:

number of variable multiplication of a^2 is 2 which are a and a , and a a' a'' is 3 which are a a' and a''.

Moreover, when i type Coefficient[z,a] in order to get multipliers of a in z;

I expected to get {a,b,a',a'a'',b'}
However i got {b,a',a'a'',b'}

Furthermore, i thought Length[a^2] would be 2 but it is not.
However Length[a b] is 2.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: what does `a'` and `a''` actually supposed to mean?

Comment: derivatives for sure...

Comment: derivatives with respect to what??

Comment: it does not matter i think...

Comment: huh? I do not understand. How could you write `a''` and expect Mathematica to process this as a derivative with respect to something that does not matter?

Comment: z = 5 a + a a + a' + a b + a c + a b c + a c' + a b' + a b' c' - 
   a' b' c' + a b'' c' + a a' + a'' a''' + a'' a'''' + a a'''' + 
   a a''' + a' b c'';

aa = Coefficient[z, {a, a', a'', a''', a''''}];

Comment: @Nasser it is possible that the author wanted to have a symbolic counting of derivatives or something to that effect. In my `a''` is not the best practice for sure. For instance they could have used `app` or something.

Comment: Further comments: with the expression as written in the OP, namely `z = a^2 + a b + a a' + a a' a'' + a b'`, I do get `Length[a^2]` is `2`. I, also, get that the output of `Coefficient[z, a]` is `b+a'+b'+a'a''` as was expected and not a LIST as presented in the OP.

Comment: i expected a+b+a'+b'+a'a'' instead of b+a'+b'+a'a'' for Coefficient[z,a] and i know a is variable here . So let me ask again. 

What should i type to get a+b+a'+b'+a'a' from z in order to take multipliers of a ???

Comment: @kcr ```Length[a^2]``` returns ```2```, as it is really counting the arguments of ```Power[a,2]```. It does not count the degree (e.g. ```Length[a^3]``` also returns ```2```)

Comment: @Hausdorff I understand that. I pointed it out because in the OP it is stated `i thought Length[a^2] would be 2 but it is not.`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Mathematica tutorial on algebraic manipulation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AlgebraicManipulation.html). Particularly the section "Polynomial Orderings" seems relevant to what you want to do.

To sort the monomials by degree you can use

```
MonomialList[z,Variables[z],"DegreeLexicographic"]
(* {a a' a'', a^2, a b, a a', a b'}*)
```

To get the multiplier of `a`, you can for example use `PolynomialReduce`

```
PolynomialReduce[z,{a},a][[1,1]]
(* a+b+a'+b'+a' a'' *)
```